# How to check from worker thread if a check box in main thread is checked?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have designed a GUI program using pyqt5. I have a main thread and a worker thread. When the GUI starts, i get some inputs from user such as age, name,checkboxs ... and i want to process the inputs in worker. In question [How to assign variables to worker Thread in Python PyQt5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74348042/how-to-assign-variables-to-worker-thread-in-python-pyqt5/74351397#74351397) i learned how to pass GUI input variables to worker thread. But now i dont know how to check a checkbox if it is checked or not? I want to access the checkbox in GUI main thread from the worker thread but i dont know how can i do this. I really appreciate answers that help me to solve this problem.
**Update:**
This is my main file (main.py):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from GUI import *
from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication,QLabel,QMainWindow,QPushButton,QVBoxLayout,QWidget,)
import os, psutil

class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        self._main_thread = kwargs.pop("_main_thread")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def run(self):
        if self.ui._main_thread.ui.check.isChecked(): #checkbox is defined in main thread
           print("yesss")

        self.finished.emit()

class MyAPP(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.Action.clicked.connect(self.runLongTask)
        self.show()


    def runLongTask(self):
       
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.thread.start()
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyAPP()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and This is the GUI file (GUI.py):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'GUI.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(548, 312)
        self.Action = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.Action.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 190, 75, 23))
        self.Action.setObjectName("Action")
        
        self.Input1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.Input1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 60, 191, 20))
        self.Input1.setObjectName("Input1")

        self.check = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(Dialog)
        self.check.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 90, 131, 31))
        self.check.setObjectName("check")
        self.check.setText( "CheckBox")
        
        self.Input2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.Input2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 120, 191, 20))
        self.Input2.setObjectName("Input2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 130, 47, 13))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.Print = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.Print.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 250, 361, 31))
        self.Print.setText("")
        self.Print.setObjectName("Print")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.Action.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ok"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Name"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Age"))
```

Comment: That same example clearly shows what you're asking in the second part (using mutex). Just create a function that does what shown and connect it with the `toggled` signal.

Answer (score -2):

since python doesn't have pointer, you can pointing some variables from `Worker` class to point the `MyAPP`

```
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._my_app = kwargs.pop("_my_app")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def run(self):
        if self._my_app.ui.myCheckbox.ischecked(): #checkbox is defined in main thread
           do something

        self.finished.emit()

class MyAPP(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setFixedSize(1180, 850)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.runWorkerBtn.clicked.connect(self.runLongTask)

   def runLongTask(self):
       
        self.thread = QThread()
     
        self.worker = Worker(_my_app=self)
  
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
       
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.thread.start()
```

Comment: How can this be an accepted answer? It uses wrong/missing attributes, and certainly doesn't solve the issue nor adds anything that was already in the original post linked in the OP.

Comment: @danangjoyoo there's no need for that, because the question was already marked as duplicate (and there would be no point in adding another one, since the problem is in the code). Instead, you could take your time to *fix* your answer.

Comment: @musicamante yes you are right. This does not solve the problem and the code crashes. I just looked at the code and i thought it is the right way to solve the thread problem but now when i tested it, i saw it does not work

Comment: @danangjoyoo Sorry but code did not work!

Comment: @musicamante I added main.py and GUI.py code to Update section. Can you please check it and help me how can i solve the problem. For example i want to write a code that if the checkbox is checked, then it prints yes

Comment: sorry but ```"_main_thread``` gives error? can you please tell what is "_main_thread?

Comment: my bad, just checked it it should be `_main_app`, answer updated

Comment: @danangjoyoo Sorry but i dont understand what is ```_main_app```?? again it does not execute and it gives error

Comment: @danangjoyoo `def __init__(*args, **kwargs):` is missing `self` as first argument. You should also avoid overwriting object attributes: [`thread`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread) is an existing function of all Qt objects and shall not be overwritten with something else (which is extremely important for a case like this that *does* deal with threading and querying an object's `thread()` might be important).

Comment: updated. is `_my_app` already an object? havent checked it